# Using variable for HTTP request headers with Perl

Tags: perl, lwp

I am trying to write a function to create HTTP requests (POST and GET mostly) in Perl. I am keeping everything generic by using variables so that I don't have to worry about the type of request, the payload, headers, etc, however HTTP::Request->header() doesn't seem to like my variable:

```
    my($req_type, $headers, $endpoint, $args, $request, $jsonfile) = @_;
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    my $req = HTTP::Request->new($req_type => $endpoint);
    $req->content_type('application/json');

    foreach (@$headers) {
        $req->push_header($_);
    }

    $req->content($args);
    $req->content($request);

    print "request : ".$req->as_string;
```

I tried a few different approches, and using push_header got me the closest, but I realize it may not be the best solution. I think it might have something to do with single quotes getting passed in:

```
@headers = "'x-auth-token' => '$_token'";
```

I can post more of the code if it is helpful. I'm hoping some Perl guru will know exactly what I'm doing wrong. I'm sure it's something to do with the format of the string I'm passing in.

Comment: Why are you passing your headers as strings rather than a hash or an array?

Comment: Lack of experience mostly... I thought I was passing them with an array?

Comment: `"'x-auth-token' => '$_token'"` is a string. An array would be `('x-auth-token' => $_token)`. An array ref would be `['x-auth-token' => $_token]`

Comment: Do you have `$headers`, which is a scalar, or `@headers`, which is an array? It's impossible to give you an answer to this question without seeing your inputs.

Comment: Ok I added the input to the code. It's coming in as `$headers` and the foreach loop is actually printing the strings from the array, but it doesn't seem right.

Comment: OK... but what does `$headers` contain?

Comment: @MattJacob $headers contains `(x_auth_token => $_token, accept => 'application/json');` The solution below worked for me. Was this question really considered "unclear" or "not useful" enough to warrant a down vote?

Comment: @user3270760 Considering that the answer to the question is completely dependent on the contents of that variable, absolutely. Please learn how to create a [mcve], and also [ask] a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> @headers = "'x-auth-token' => '$_token'";

The header function expects to be passed **two** arguments. The header name and the header value.

You are passing it **one** argument: a string containing a fragment of Perl code.

You need to format your data more sensibly.

---

```
my %headers = (
    "x-auth-token" => $_token;
);
```

and

```
foreach my $header_name (keys %headers) {
    $req->push_header($header_name => $headers{$header_name});
}
```

Comment: Why not just `$req->header(%headers)`?

Comment: @MattJacob — If that syntax works, then great, but I didn't notice it when skimming the docs.

Comment: It doesn't like the barewords I'm using in the hash now. It's complaining about "x" and "auth". Is there a trick I can use to fool it?

Comment: @user3270760 — Ooops. Put quotes around it.

Comment: @user3270760 What barewords? Without seeing your data, it's very, very difficult to help you. Remember---we're not looking over your shoulder right now, so help us out a little.